# Get request doesn't work - Angular 4

Tags: angular, api, request

I'm new to Angular 4, I'm trying to make  simple app with an api. But the Get request doesn't work and I don't understand what the problem is.

My Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RequestService {

// persos:any;


constructor(private http:Http) {

    this.getPersos();

}

getPersos() {

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'people/')
        .map(response => {
            return response.json(),
            console.log(response.json());
        })
}
```

My component file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { RequestService } from '../services/requests.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'persos',
  templateUrl: './persos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./persos.component.css'],
  providers: [RequestService]
})


export class PersosComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private requestService:RequestService) {
    console.log(this.persos);
}

title = 'List des personnages';
persos;

ngOnInit() {

    this.requestService.getPersos()
        .subscribe(persos => {
            this.persos = persos;
            console.log(this.persos);
        }) 
}

}
```

In the service file, I put a log who return to me the good datas, bu the console.log inside the component file return 'undefined'.

I didn't find a solution yet.
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add your console.log inside the subscribe, also your component method method should be

```
 this.requestService.getPersos().subscribe(persos => {
        this.persos = persos;
        console.log(this.persos);
 });
```

and your Service should be,

```
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'people/')
    .map(response => {
       return response.json(),
         console.log(response.json());
    })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When I do that it return 'udefined' too.

Comment: did you change the service as mentioned above

Comment: In the service, instead of just response.json(), you should have **return** response.json()

Comment: [EDIT] I put the return but it's always undifed

Comment: @QuentinIcky you need to return the response inside your sevice method. there is a return response.json()

Comment: did you put the console.log inside the subscribe?

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestions. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Nope only 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the API URL that you are trying to access exists/works? Also, I'm a little suspicious about this code.

```
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'people/')
    .map(response => {
        response.json(),
        console.log(response.json());
    })
```

You have `response => {response.json(), console.log(response.json());})` and I have a feeling that doesn't work.

Also, when you `subscribe()` an observable, you don't set the value to the subscription. You would set the value in a function inside the subscribe() call.

```
this.requestService.myMethod().subscribe(result => {
    this.persos = result;
    console.log(this.persos);
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Yep the url exist I just didn't include it here. For the request part, it works. I get the good datas in the console.
And when I set the value in a function, as you proposed, the error disapear but it returns 'udefined'.